# Determine Windows drive letter using PHP

Tags: php, server, system, drive-letter

I looked a little bit but didn't find the answer. Is it possible to find out the servers system drive/folder without any hacks?

In the answer that you provided it's only discussed how to determine current drive, but I need to find out the system drive, where the OS installed.

Comment: I think if you have the `COM` class, you are able to do that. Not sure if there is an command to use with `exec()`. These may be the only options. There aren't any native PHP commands (the question is why should they add that). Google can maybe help more with windows related cli commands.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, what COM class? Also, on the server side we have nothing except usual php enironment, sometimes stricted to exec commands. I thought there must be some functions to do the trick.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Possible duplicate but not 100% sure as the web root's location can be on a different drive than the OS.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois You have a point, I didnt grasp the `system` bit on first reading, close removed

Comment: Try looking at `$_SERVER["SystemRoot"]` although I am not sure what that will return on a UNIX environment

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, interesting info. Maybe I will use it as plan B if nothing more will be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows:

```
echo GetEnv("SystemDrive");
// C:
```

On Unix/Linux this variable doesn't exist though, but there the system "drive" is predictably just `/`.

if you need the actual partition, you can try to get it with this:

```
exec( 'mount |grep " / " | cut -d " " -f 1' );
// /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Thanks for linux tip. Also, one more question - using GetEnv or $_SERVER can I actually find out OS name?

Comment: You can see all available environment variables with [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), `$_SERVER` can be inspected like all variables with [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).